# Automatic start parse server

Tags: ubuntu, parse-platform, digital-ocean, parse-server

Parse server automatic start on the server. how can i add automatic start or always on for the parse server im using digital ocean ubuntu for it. and i need to start the application by opening terminal and adding the code below

```
cd parse-server-example 
npm start 

parse-dashboard --config config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1
```

Im using ubuntu on my server

Comment: onBoot - launcher   https://github.com/OpenLabTools/OpenLabTools/wiki/Launching-bash-scripts-at-startup

Comment: maybe you can try forever?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pm2 as mentioned in [this article](https://medium.com/@at0dd/parse-server-and-dashboard-on-ubuntu-4d66b8cdbd84):

> ```
> pm2 start index.js
> pm2 startup
> pm2 save
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. You could use Docker: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-host-a-node-js-app-on-digital-ocean

You could also use something similar to Digital Ocean's guide to hosting a production app, though instead of `hello.js` you'll want a bash script that calls npm start for your parse-server.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

We use pm2 relatively successfully. (I wasn't the one who set it up so can't comment on ease of use)

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/